# How to present a "floating" message?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

When a password has been changed successfully and this modal form is closed...

[image]

...I want to show a small window in the bottom-right corner of the page/browser saying "Password changed" for 1 or 2 seconds (then it would automatically disappear) if no backdrop is clicked.

[image]

If possible, I'd like to place it in the visible area of the component/router-outlet.

I am using Angular with Bootstrap and Ngb - perhaps they have something onboard to use.

Comment: for this you can use any toaster library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is a very simple thing to do on your own, or you can just use a toaster package like Vivek just shared

Comment: Yes, indeed you can use the toaster library to do exactly this. Please see here for a tutorial: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/07/05/angular-8-alert-toaster-notifications

Comment: thanks. i didnt know what to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NGB has alert or Toast which might fit your need. With proper styling, we can set the positioning too.

```
 <ngb-alert [type]="alert.type" (close)="close(alert)">{{ alert.message }}</ngb-alert>

<ngb-toast header="Notification header">
  Content of the notification
</ngb-toast>
```

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/examples
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/overview